# How to request for Facebook XMPP chat permission in iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api, xmpp

My app needs to send a private message to the user's Facebook friend. The user needs to grant the XMPP permission before my app can do this.

```
[[FBSession activeSession]
    requestNewPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        @"publish_stream",
        @"xmpp_login",
        nil
    ]
    defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone
    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
    }
];
```

The above code will pop up this alert view as expected:

[image]

However, even before tapping any button, this warning is printed out in the debug log:

> FBSDKLog: FBSession: a permission request for publish or manage
>   permissions contains unexpected read permissions

Surely enough, after tapping the "OK" button, the completion handler comes back with an error, containing the same warning. I understand that the Facebook API requires asking for read and write permissions separately, but the xmpp_login permission seems to need both read and write at the same time. I'm at a dead end here.

- iOS 7.1
- Facebook SDK 3.12.0
- Xcode 5.1

Comment: Do you have Chat Demo So please give me .thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the section **Extended Permissions** in [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-extended).

According to this, `xmpp_login` is the **read** permission, not the write/publish permission. So you should add that the readPermission

Comment: But what if I need to do more than *read* people's messages? I need to *write* messages.

Comment: That's fine. To integrate the Chat API you just need to have the `xmpp_login` permission and that is the *read* permission.